# Do null reference type variables impact garbage collector (GC) performance?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

IIRC, the generation-based garbage collector in the .NET Framework determines which objects are still alive by scanning through your process's memory looking for references. Does the quantity of reference type variables (particularly, those that have been set to `null`) impact the speed of this scan?

For instance, in my application, I'm designing sort of a grid container that is expected to store alot of empty `Cell`. Since `Cell` (in this example) contains a reference type variable, each instance of `Cell` adds +1 to the quantity of reference type variables in my application.

```
struct Cell { public SomeReferenceType objRef; }
```

If only a small percentage of those cells have a `objRef` not `null`, am I inadvertently hurting the performance of the GC?

Comment: Well, it will have to look to see that they are/aren't null - but it is quite good at that, and it isn't prohibitively expensive. Are you seeing a performance problem?

Comment: Wrong question, there's not much to fear from background GC.  Much harder to hide having to plow through hundreds of "do nothing" references when you, say, paint the grid.

Comment: What alternative are you comparing it to?  Without knowing how your application would be designed when trying to avoid it it's rather hard to know if the costs your incurring here are wasteful, or simply a necessary result of the complexity of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally tracing GC can be divided in two parts: checking reachability and removing unreachable objects. When you're only creating more references without adding any unreachable objects, you don't impact the work needed for the second part, but every (reachable) reference must be visited to determine reachability for the whole object graph. This is assuming the structs are reachable (if they aren't, e.g. because they are part of an array that was orphaned, they are never visited).

That said, this work is minuscule, a single pointer comparison and a conditional branch (which will be predicted correctly if most references are indeed `null`). This goes doubly if you those structs are part of a large array (which is the only way I can see you getting a lot of structs without introducing many other non-null references).

A non-null reference is more expensive because the GC has to follow it (-> potential cache miss) and possible traverse a large object subgraph (-> lots of extra work) that's reachable through said reference.

Comment: This is NaN more helpful than conjecturing "wrong question"; thank you. :)